# Call C# Web API from Outlook Web Add-in

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, azure-active-directory, msal

I have created a ASP.NET MVC Web API, which is hosted in azure. It has a ClientID which clients needs to authenticate against when calling its actionmethods.

Now I have created a Outlook Web Add-in and added my add-in in the appointments ribbon.
The users log onto https://outlook.office.com/ and gets authenticated.
Then they are able to access the add-in in the appointments ribbon.
When the user clicks on the add-in icon, the add-in panel is loaded on the right side of the window.

In my add-in i need to fill out some dropdowns and so on, so i need to load the data from the Web API.

So first I need to authenticate the user. I have read some articles where they suggest using the msal.js library. In my add-in i have this part trying to authenticate the user:

```
Office.onReady(function (info) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // The document is ready
        GetAccessToken();
    });
});

function GetAccessToken() {

    //************** acquireTokenSilent
    console.log('configuring msal...');
    var msalConfig = {
        auth: {
            clientId: <web pi client it>,
            authority: <my authority>,
            redirectUri: <configured redirect uri on azure for the web api app reg.>
        },
        cache: {
            cacheLocation: "sessionStorage",
            storeAuthStateInCookie: false
        }
    };
    var msalInstance = new msal.PublicClientApplication(msalConfig);
    console.log('msal configured');
    
    msalInstance.acquireTokenPopup({
        scopes: ["User.Read"]
    })
    .then(response => {
        // Handle token acquisition
        window.close(); // Close the popup window

        // Acquire token interactive success
        // Call API with token
        console.log('token acquired');
        accessToken = response.accessToken;
        console.log('access token: ' + accessToken);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        // Acquire token interactive failure
        console.log('error acquiring token: ' + error);
    });
}
```

When running the code the popup shows and authenticates the user. But then in the popup it shows the web api index page, instead of closing so i can retrieve the access token.

I want the popup to close so i can retrieve the access token, and then add that in the header for my calls to the API.

I tried to manually close the popup with the window.close(), but that did not work.

How do i do make the popup automatically close?

Comment: After successful authentication, the MSAL.js library will only redirect to the URL address that you mentioned in the property `redirectUri`, you need to handle in that page how to behave further - for e.g to get the bearer token from MSAL and then make your API call using jquery/ajax/C# httpClient from your addin..

Answer (score 0):

```js
 let dialog;
    function login() {
        let a = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=Add your client id here without any space &response_type=token&redirect_uri= your redirect_uri &scope=user.read%20mail.readwrite%20mail.send&response_mode=fragment&state=12345&nonce=678910";
        //let a = "https://localhost:44397/Redirect.html";

        // mailboxItem.body.getAsync("html", { asyncContext: event }, checkBodyOnlyOnSendCallBack);
        // Declare dialog as global for use in later functions.
        Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync(a, { height: 30, width: 20 },
            function (asyncResult) {
                dialog = asyncResult.value;
                dialog.addEventHandler(Office.EventType.DialogMessageReceived, processMessage);
            }
        );
    }
    function processMessage(arg) {
        dialog.close();
        let messageFromDialog = JSON.parse(arg.message);
        console.log("accessToken", messageFromDialog)
      //  window.localStorage.setItem("accessToken", messageFromDialog)
    }
```

Add this code in your Redirect.html file

```
<script src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/office.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>


        var address_Link = window.location.href;
        console.log(address_Link)
        var address_arr = address_Link.split("=");
        var address_Token = address_arr[1];
        var Id_Token = address_Token.split("&");
        var access_token = Id_Token[0];
        console.log(Id_Token)

        Office.onReady(function (appInfo) {
            Office.context.ui.messageParent(JSON.stringify(access_token));

</script>
```

I loin url add your client id and your redirect_uri.
when login successfully you will receive Access Token in your js.
hopefully it is helpful for you I tried my best to explain you.

Comment: Thanks user19919855. i will give it a go and come back with the results.